# Matching contents of list with csv rows gives no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So, I've a list of links like ['abc','def',....]. I have a csv file of which the  fourth column consists only links and each row contains brand name, product name, price, link, img link etc. I'm trying to access the csv file and find if any item of the list is in any of the rows of the csv file and if the csv contains then print that row only. The code is below :

```
print("\n\nHere are the related products in our database:\n\n")
for eachhm in hmlist:
    with open('allinone.csv', mode='r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for num, row in enumerate(reader):
            if eachhm in row:
                dbmatch = "\n\nNo: "+str(num)+", \nBrand Name: "+str(row[0]) + ", \nProduct Name: " + str(row[1]) + ", \nPrice per unit: " + str(row[2]) + ", \nProduct Link: " + str(row[3]) + ", \nProduct Image link : " + str(row[4])
                print(dbmatch)
```

Here is the first few lines from the csv file :
[image: csv sample]

However, it only prints the first line ["Here are ..."] but never shows any row from the csv fie even when the list contains a link specifically present in the csv file. Where's the error ?

Comment: Please show us about 10 lines of the CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Pandas` to read a `.csv` file.

They have a function `Pandas.read_csv('file_name.csv')`

Comment: This doen't solve the issue but as no other solution is there, I'm forced to try it !

Comment: I could try to help if you could share file. Do you have header rows which are inconsistent with other rows?